# Strange behavior with coordinate transformation of square and quadrilateral

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, quadratics, interpolation

I am trying to map coordinates from a quadrilateral to a square. The coordinates are

square:
$(500,900)(599,900)(599,999)(500,999)$

quad:
$(454,945)(558,951)(598,999)(499,999)$

where the $i^{th}$ entry are corresponding corners. It looks like this:

[image]

I am following the **method 2** from this article
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bilinearwarp/FourCornerImageWarp2.pdf

Based on its instructions, I can make these two matrices:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 500 & 900 & 450000 \\ 1 & 599 & 900 & 539100 \\ 1 & 599 & 999 & 598401 \\ 1 & 500 & 999 & 499500 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 454 \\ 558 \\ 598 \\ 499 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 500 & 900 & 450000 \\ 1 & 599 & 900 & 539100 \\ 1 & 599 & 999 & 598401 \\ 1 & 500 & 999 & 499500 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} b_0 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 945 \\ 951 \\ 999 \\ 999 \end{bmatrix}$

If I solve for them I get

$a0=-709.911845730028$

$a1=1.50964187327824$

$a2=0.709621467197225$

$a3=-0.000510152025303541$

$b0=148.305785123967$

$b1=0.611570247933884$

$b2=0.85154576063667$

$b3=-0.000612182430364249$

But then when I run this python script (I want to simulate manually, converting the point (454, 945) on the quad to the point (500,900) on the square), I get a different answer. I get (442.90822654, 1024.0)...

```
X = 454
Y = 945

a0=-709.911845730028
a1=1.50964187327824
a2=0.709621467197225
a3=-0.000510152025303541


b0=148.305785123967 
b1=0.611570247933884 
b2=0.85154576063667 
b3=-0.000612182430364249

A = b2*a3 - b3*a2
C_one = (b0*a1 - b1*a0)
C = C_one + (b1*X - a1*Y)
B_one = (b0*a3 - b3*a0) + (b2*a1 - b1*a2)
B = B_one + (b3*X - a3*Y)

V = (-B + (B*B - 4*A*C)**0.5 ) / (2*A)
U = (X - a0 - a2*V) / (a1 + a3*V)

print U,V
```

I tried a test where I warp an image, filled with different quads. It mostly worked except for two areas, ie.. the left eye and right leg. The above example is for the case of the right leg.

original image:
[image]

warped image:
[image]

warp template:
[image]

The quad that I am using for the above example is in the last row in the middle, to the right of the red/maroon quad.

Does anyone know what is going on? Is it possibly a numerical/rounding error? But it did work with all the quads except two of them.

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to map points on a 2d quadrilateral to a 2d square like in the first image above. The article I put the link on has 3 methods on doing it, and I am trying to do the second method, but its not working for a particular case which I outlined above. Its mostly working but fails on 2 places which I want to find out why.

Comment: It is possible to map a general quadrilateral to a square in various ways.  It is not possible to do the mapping in all cases with a linear or even an affine transformation of $\mathbb {R}^2$.  Your use of a $4\times 4$ matrix might work for some cases that a $2\times 2$ matrix does not, but it is unclear how you defined the $a_i, b_i $ entries you want to populate the column vectors with.  It is also unclear what you consider wrong in your results.

Comment: In the article they say `X=a0+Ua1+Va2+UVa3` and `Y=b0+Ub1+Vb2+UVb3` (where U,V is square and X,Y is quad), so I put in the corner points (cardinal points) which I know what they map to (i.e. I specified it on the very top). When putting them in I get 8 equations (these two repeated 4 times). And then it is easy to put them in matrix form. I have two matrix because $a_i$ and $b_i$ are independent. The problem is in the second android image. See the left eye and right foot. It looks like it got corrupted there, the mapping is off. And My example on top shows the mapping got messed up somehow.

Comment: Basically in the quads in those two areas, the mapping didn't get mapped to the right coordinates on the square. This is illustrated by the example I put above. Which is the top left pixel of the quad of the right foot.

Comment: I was able to improve the result by scaling the square to a unit square, but the result is not perfect yet.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are applying the same map $(u,v) \to (x,y)$ to all the "quads" in your image.  It is possible for the map to twist points out of any recognizable quadrilateral image, even smashing points together.  I could explain the mathematical properties of the mapping, often called a "bilinear quadrilateral element", but that doesn't seem to address your concern that "the mapping got messed up somehow".  In most applications you would define a grid of squares or quadrilaterals, and solve for the required mapping on each small section.

Comment: I solve the whole thing I did above for every quad and I don't reuse it. I also calculate the quads from these curved quads by detecting the corners.

Comment: Well, I cannot "debug" what might going wrong from looking at the images.  The minimal, complete, and verifiable example would be to give the four vertices of a quadrilateral and show that it fails to map as you wish to the four corners of a unit square.  If you were mapping each quad separately to the same unit square, of course the image would be very different than what you have displayed.

Comment: Lol that's what I did with the above example. It's one of the two  quad that got messed vales. This is my way to debug it

Comment: You wrote "I am trying to map coordinates from a quadrilateral to a square."  It makes no sense to blame a mapping from a quadrilateral to a square for bad values in the quadrilateral.

Comment: But I picked a corner point how is that bad value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26726/discussion-between-hardmath-and-omega).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion about the direction of the mapping seems to be deeply embedded in the question.  The article describes a way of mapping a square to a (curved) quadrilateral using what is often called the "bilinear quadrilateral element" in the literature.

This is not a linear transformation, and because it contains a quadratic term, it is not trivial to invert the mapping.

**Added:**

The OP has apparently diagnosed the problem.  The Python code mapping in the opposite direction, from the quadrilateral to the square, needs to solve a quadratic.  When two roots are nearly equal, care ought to be taken in evaluating the roots via the usual quadratic formula to avoid "catastrophic cancellation" by having terms of like sign in the numerator.  The OP reports (see Comment) that after taking this measure the mapping works as expected.

Comment: I fixed it using the formula for quadratic equation here http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c5-6.pdf. The issue was probably catastrophic cancellation or round off error. Now my image looks perfect.