# Most stable algorithm to solve a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am doing some image processing involving solving a system of linear equations. I am getting some errors and bits of the image looks corrupted. I would like to know what is the most stable way to solve these systems (I don't care how much cpu it takes to compute). It should try to avoid roundoff, catastrophic cancellation, etc...

Does anyone know the best method? (then I would need to find a way to code it in c#)

BTW I am implementing method 2 from here http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bilinearwarp/FourCornerImageWarp2.pdf and this is for solving the coefficients in the equations.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the linear system, not the quadratic equation?

Comment: It could be the quadratic equation too. Is there a better way to do the quadratic equation?

Comment: Please take a look at http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c5-6.pdf

Comment: Also, I don't see any linear systems in the attached paper

Comment: It's the 3a,3b equations that I repeat 4 times because of the 4 corners, then I can separate it into two systems since ai and bi are independent and represent it as matrix form.

Comment: Am I correct that the system you're solving is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}x_0\\ x_1 \\ x_3 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Do you really need a matrix solver for that?

Comment: No that's not the matrix. rows are of the form 1 u v uv where each row is a uv coordinate of the corner.

Comment: And the UV coordinates of the corners are $(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)$ and $(0, 1)$

Comment: see this other thread of mine regarding the same problem
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387893/strange-behavior-with-coordinate-transformation-of-square-and-quadrilateral

Comment: I was able to improve the result by scaling the square to a unit square, but the result is not perfect yet.

Comment: You should use unit square, otherwise your mapping is badly conditioned. Also, shifting $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(0, 0)$ should improve things

Comment: Does it matter if I shift first then scale, or scale then shift?

Comment: I think $(x,y) \overset{\text{shift}}{\to} (x - x_0, y - y_0) \overset{\text{transform}}{\to} (U, V) \overset{\text{scale}}{\to} (X, Y)$, with $0 \leq U, V \leq 1$, $(X, Y)$ are the original coordinates, $(x,y)$ are resulting coordinates

Comment: Im not sure what u mean, I have to apply this to a square thats at an arbitrary location anywhere.

Comment: The article you posted, worked for me, now my image looks perfect.